# afterPostback event with Context.ReturnFile

Tags: dotvvm

I've found out that the `afterPostback` event is not being called when `Context.ReturnFile()` is used in the `ViewModel`. I use the following code to disable all the buttons on the page when postback is sent and enable them again after the `postback` is finished:

```
dotvvm.events.beforePostback.subscribe(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').prop('disabled', true).addClass('m-progress');
});
dotvvm.events.afterPostback.subscribe(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('m-progress');
});
```

However, when some `ViewModel` uses `Context.ReturnFile()` to return a generated file, the `afterPostback` is not called and all the buttons on the page stay disabled.

I've also tried to use `spaNavigating` and `spaNavigated` events, but they don't seem to be called either.

Is there some workaround or another event that is called when a file is returned from `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context.ReturnFile` uses redirect internally and redirect doesn't fire this event.

I have filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm/issues/385) and we will see if we can change the behavior for the  `afterPostback` event to be called on redirects. If not, we will introduce a new event just for this case.